# Como implementar el PERMISO DE ID DE PUBLICIDAD de Google Play, en código de C# en el editor de Unity 2020?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity, unity2d

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimad@s

Su gentil ayuda, Google Play Store, al momento de subir una aplicacion de tipo juego realizado en Unity version 2020, me solicita que declare un "permiso de ID de publicacion", el mismo que estuve indagando durante horas en como poder implementarlo en el juego; me indican en la documentación encontrara, que se debe declararse una linea de codigo en el "Manifest.xml" en la cual se muestre el permiso de "AD_ID", sin embargo al ser codigo de "C#" que se programa, y que posterior el Unity lo compila en la plataforma destinada, que en mi caso resulta ser para dispositivos mobiles "Android", realiza la dicha transformación de manera automatica, lo cual me dificulta la forma de lograr encontrar un paso intermedio para añadir dicha linea de codigo en el "Manifest.xml".

Linea de Codigo que se debe Implementar en el Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

Dicha documentación la encontré en el siguiente link:

https://docs.unity.com/ads/InstallingTheAndroidSDK.html

En esta dirección me indican que si se posee un Unity Ads SDK version 4.1 or superior, se salte ese paso, caso contrario si en inferior a la 4.0.1, se debe realizar manualmente.

Su amable ayuda, si alguien conoce la forma de implementarlo en codigo de "C#", en el editor de Unity, ya que asumo que dispongo de una versión inferior del SDK de Unity Ads.

Muchas Gracias
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Este mensaje lo envió Google y aplica para aplicaciones Android nativas o creadas usando Flutter o Xamarin. **Aplicará si tu aplicación contiene anuncios Google y tu aplicación este orientada a API 31**:

```
targetSdkVersion 31
```

El `AD_ID` (ID de publicidad) que es un identificador único usado para rastrear usos y movimientos de las aplicaciones por parte del usuario.

Los dispositivos con Android 12 (API level 31) o superior ya tienen la función de eliminar este ID de publicidad de sus dispositivos, por eso **es importante que si tu app usa anuncios Google y esta orientada a Android 12 (API level 31) o superior, se debe proporcionar permiso para acceder a `AD_ID`**.

Este es el permiso que debes definir:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```